# How to find files asssociated with a ClearCase UCM activity?

Tags: clearcase

Can someone help me with the following question: How can I find files that were checked in with some activity.

For example:

I am working on a view called `syoffe_my_product_view` and in the past I created an activity - `BUG123_activity`.
Now I need to find all the files that were checked in with this activity

What command/option do you recommend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [cleartool lsactivity man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm):

```
 cleartool lsactivity -l activity-id@\aPVob      # (windows)
 cleartool lsactivity -l activity-id@/vobs/aPVob # (unix)
```

You have also the describe option with [fmt_ccase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)

```
 cleartool describe -fmt "%[versions]CQp"  activity-title@\aPVob
```

In both cases, make sure to use the activity **ID** and noy the activity "`headline`":

[image]

The activity above, for instance, woiuld need `test1_24342`, not `test1` (its "Headline")

If you execute it:

- **outside your view**, you will get the extended paths for all the *versions* recorded in this activity.
- **within your view**, you will get the paths.

Answer (score 1):

```
cleartool lsact -l
```

There are another options but this is a good one for starting...

Tamir

Comment: thx for the answer but running it in my view gives no output. The activity I need to query was used in the past and I need to find the list of files that are associated with it

Comment: You have to provide <activity-id>@<pvob-name> at the end of this command. See "cleartool man lsact" for further details

Answer (score 0):

If you have ClearTeam Explorer follow these steps,

- Open ClearTeam Navigator.
- Click **My Views-**> [*some view*] ->**My
  Activities**.
- Clear Team Details tab will open with list of
  activities created by you.
- Right click on specific activity and
  select Show Change Set.
- ClearCase Change Set tab will open and lists
  Check-in files under specific activity.