# What is the environment variable to get the change set of UCM activity?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a trigger set which fires when a delivery is completed. It sends an email with the information about the stream name, activity name etc. I also want to include the change set of the activity that was delivered. How do I do this? Which env variable would consist this information when a delivery is being done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `CLEARCASE_ACTIVITY`.
(UCM activities are the official names for "change sets": when you access the "properties" of an UCM activity, you see a tab called "change set")

As that thread mentions, this only work for a **post-op** trigger, not a pre-op.

This technote illustrates the use of such a variable:

```
cleartool mktrtype -ucmobject -all -postop deliver_complete
  -mkhlink UndelAct@\TEST_PVOB,to=%CLEARCASE_ACTIVITY% -nc
  trtype:UndelAct@\TEST_PVOB
```

However, that would give you the delivered activity (called "`deliver.xxx`"), not the source activities.
For that, you need to list all activities *contributing* to that delivered activity:
See "**[Finding which developer activities were delivered in a specific delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14022262/6309)**"

```
cleartool lsact -contrib activityName@\aPVob
```

---

The [OP clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525609/clearcase) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989362/what-is-the-environment-variable-to-get-the-change-set-of-ucm-activity/19989533#comment29760957_19989533):

> It does not provide the list offiles that were delivered.

For that, you don't need the list of contributing activities.
You can simply describe the resulting baseline in `CLEARCASE_ACTIVITY` (the "`deliver.xxx`" one)

See "[**How to find files asssociated with a ClearCase UCM activity?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10632818/6309)":

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[versions]CQp"  activity-title@\aPVob
```

Comment: I am using a perl script to get this information and send an email. I am pulling the CLEARCASE_ACTIVITY environment variable but it only finds the name of the activity i.e deliver.<stream_name>.<timestamp>@/<pvob>. It does not provide the list offiles that were delivered.

Comment: I just saw your edit. I will check out the link that was provided

Comment: @clearcase I just edited, again, my answer, to address your comment.